# SKlabelNode custom font

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I know I can create a custom font using this code:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"bebas-neue" size:10];
```

But if I want to create an SKLabelNode, how can I set this as the font?

SKLabelNode only takes a string as the fontName.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure is essentially the same as for `UIFont`.

To do this from scratch, follow the same process as for adding a custom UIFont (described [here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)), then just use:

```
[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Font Name Here"]
```