# How do I display a string of digits with custom design?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I don't want to use `SKLabelNode` because I want to have special effects like a gradient fill, a shadow, and a custom font, so I created 10 `png` images, one for each digit, and I added them as an image atlas. Then, when setting up the number to display, I create for each digit a new `SKSpriteNode` with the texture of the digit from the atlas, and add it to a parent `SKSpriteNode` with no texture. The problem I'm having with this is that I'm trying to set the anchor point to the middle of all the nodes added, but when setting the anchor point, it's only setting the anchor point relative to its own frame, which is not updated when child nodes are added.

I've worked on it some more and I can't quite get the sprites centered. Here's a subclass of `SKNode` where I'm doing this: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DrOverbuild/9ad9f92f1b2ea66bf5727cfa874fab49). When I create an instance of this node, set the position to 0,0, set `currentValue`, and add the node to the game scene, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJZco.png). The box under it is a `SKShapeNode` with a frame of the number node's accumulated frame and the same position as the number node. The black dot is 0,0 on the game scene.

Is there a better way to do it? Or what can I do to fix my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want the digits to be centered on the center of all the digits? For example, if your number is 01234, you want it to look like the center is on the 2?

Comment: Well, yes, basically center of the accumulated frame. I want to fix the anchor point there so when I set the parent's position, that's where the center is set.

Comment: I would assume when you add your digits, you position them relative to the "center". This would mean items on the left would have negative X coords, items on the right have positive X coords. Once done, then your parent node is the center.

Comment: Well, easier said than done, especially when the digit sprites have varying widths. You might want to take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DrOverbuild/9ad9f92f1b2ea66bf5727cfa874fab49), especially the `updateDigit()` function, where possibly I"m doing something wrong.

Comment: Instead of using sprites,  you can rip the path from a UIFont, and use SKShape that way.  Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172207/get-path-to-trace-out-a-character-in-an-ios-uifont

Comment: To do what you want,  just set the anchor point to (0,0) on the group node,  then just subtract 1/2 width and 1/2 height of the group node from the position of the group node to always have it centered

Comment: SKNode doesn't have the property `anchorPoint`, and setting the anchor point of an SKSpriteNode isn't relative to the whole node, including children. It's relative to only the frame of the node itself excluding the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic UI stuff, whether it be for games or other applications. "Easier said than done" is more of a state of mind. When it comes to complexity in building games, this is the simple stuff.

Anyways, the key to this is you need to know how to get the width of you number. This problem is the same for any text for that matter. So if you understand how to do this, you can actually make your own custom fonts.

Below is some "code". It won't compile and I have not filled out methods. The reason for this is manifold. First and foremost, you will get more benefit out of learning by doing. Additionally, I have no idea how you are doing your stuff and it's tedious to type out all the details for a project that is not mine.

For this I'm creating a fictitious class `NumberLabel`. This is a combo `SKNode`/"custom font" class. In reality, I would separate the two. But for now, this was done for simplicity (albeit *very messy* as a byproduct that I would not build it in a singular class).

```
class NumberLabel {
    // Root for all digits. This is also the "center"
    var root:SKNode = SKNode()

    private var underlyingValue:UInt = 0

    // These will hold each digit, for example 1234 will be [1, 2, 3, 4]
    private var digits: Array<UInt>

    var value: UInt {
        get {
           return underlyingValue
        }

        set {
            // There is no optimization checks (ie. if underlyingValue != newValue, you can do that later WHEN you get this working properly)
            underlyingValue = newValue

            // Release old nodes

            // You will build your other nodes here
            buildDigits()

            let width = getWidth()
            let x = -width / 2
            let y = ??? // Determine what your y should be based on your anchoring policy for sprites

            // I now know that -width/2
            for (digit in digits) {
                // This is all pseudo code
                var digitNode = createDigitNodeForDigit(digit, x, y)

                // You need to determine any trailing spacing, this would be also accounted for in getWidth
                x += getWidthOfDigit(digit)

                root.addChild(digitNode)
            }
        }
    }
    // Initialization omitted

    // Build the digits array
    // For laziness this uses underlyingValue. Safer would be to take it as an argument, but this is just example code
    private func buildDigits() {
        // Populate array based on the number value
        // For example 1234 will be the array [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }

    // Get's width of underlyingValue (use float if you want)
    // For laziness of writing this, it assumes BOTH underlyingValue and digits are properly assigned
    public func getWidth() -> UInt {
        // Get the width of the number
        // Traverse your digits array, determine the width based on number, and insert any kerning (if appropropiate)
    }

    // Use float if you want
    public func getHeight() -> UInt {
        // Return height. While width may not be uniform, for digits, there should be uniform height
    }
}
```

So some key takeaways:

- I have not derived from `SKNode`. You are free to do so. I never derive from `SKNode` myself for classes like this. I use a "has a" versus "is a" approach for these cases. Subclass if you want, it won't change things too much.
- `getWidth` is your friend. Any font system you are building needs this as a corner stone. It is by which you render but also the means for placement within the UI.
- There are assumptions you know your widths or will derive them. You'll need them
- There is an assumption you know how to go from number to individual digits. You will use this to populate `digits`
- This is all meant to be a fast example, so my interfaces are sloppy. They don't take arguments whereas a cleaner interface for this would
- `createDigitNodeForDigit` would be your method to take a digit value (0-9) and create your `SKSpriteNode` or "digit node" object
- `getWidthOfDigit` would be your method to get the width of that digit. Presumably you can just query the width of the texture. It's up to you on how you want to deal with spacing between digits
- Note that we only do this on the setting of the value. Thus you are not incurring deconstruction and construction of the nodes every frame.

I answered a similar question here: [Add custom "number" images to SKLabelNode in as a Score in SpriteKit with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439770/add-custom-number-images-to-sklabelnode-in-as-a-score-in-spritekit-with-swift/39441461#39441461)

So maybe that has some other info for you to absorb.

Comment: So basically you're saying that I should calculate the width of the number label _before_ actually adding any digit sprites? Also, what exactly do you mean by "Safer would be to take it as an argument"? I don't see anything wrong with adding a setter to `value`.

Comment: Yes, calculate first prior to adding the digit sprites. It's the only way for you to determine the proper offsetting you need. Safer in the sense that it is dependent upon pre-populating `underlyingValue` and `digits`. If you had arguments it would be more utilitarian too. How you wish to proceed with that is really up to you.

Comment: Oh yeah, another advantage of "safer" would be you do not have to have `digits` as a property. The really is no reason to keep it around since you only need it upon digit sprite addition.